# Kendo UI AngularJS click event is taking more than 2 seconds

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

We are using AngularJS directives supported by KendoUI for jQuery. While analyzing one of the UI performance issues, I found that the click event is taking more than 2 seconds, attached is the scr[image]eenshot. What potentially could be causing this delay?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the html code of the page where this click occurs?

There are two possible reasons that come to mind:

1. There is heavy logic on the view that is being executed needlessly each time the page is refreshed instead of being done one time and only read on each refresh of the page.
2. This is less likely since it will loop forever but it's possible you keep changing a value on the view which causes another digest of the page over and over again until it is stabilized on some value.

The first option is mst likely and I've seen it before happen for a colleague.